# Apache monitoring busy vs idle workers

Tags: performance-monitoring, apache-2.2, monitoring

For Apache, I want to monitor

1. Busy workers
2. Idle workers
3. Queued requests

Monitoring would be done throughout the day, taking a sample every min., in a graphical manner.

If such a tool is not available for free, then any script which can dump this data in a tabular format and I can import that data in CSV format would be sufficient.

Is there any tool for doing that ?

Comment: How married are you to the idea of a pre-existing tool?  And how precisely do you define "in a graphical manner"?  "Must be GUI", or "must plot graphs"?

Comment: Hi womble, Any script, which can generate this data in a tabular format will do, If I can dump that data in an csv file that would be excellent.

Answer (score 2):

For the busy and idle workers, you can parse it from the [status](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_status.html) page, something like this:

```
busy_workers=`lynx -dump http://domain.com/server-status?auto | awk '/BusyWorkers/ { print $2 }'`
idle_workers=`lynx -dump http://domain.com/server-status?auto | awk '/IdleWorkers/ { print $2 }'`
```

For the waiting requests, you can calculate the numbers of concurrent connections and subtract to `MaxClients` directive:

```
concurrent_connections=`netstat -natp | grep httpd | grep ESTABLISHED | grep -v grep | wc -l`
```

From this result, you can plot a graph with any monitoring tools you want: gmetric (Ganglia), PNP4Nagios, ...

Answer (score 1):

We use [cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) with the Apache stats script, basically it parses the Server-Status page and generates the rrd Graph for cacti.

Cacti frontend is in php and stores data in MySQL. Also requires snmp ([installation](http://www.cacti.net/downloads/docs/html/install_unix.html)).